# SQL Trace Scripted for one database using DBID shows trace for all database

Tags: sql-server-2005

Hi I am running a trace over 2 days. One of the server has been noted to be decommissioned but i want to be sure by running a trace for any activity on a particular Database. I have setup my trace using the GUI and exported it to a .sql file for sql 2005. I have run the .sql file via Management Studio. When i look at the trace there are activities for other databases in the profile.

Please advice on any option I have missed.

Thanks

Comment: You haven't told us anything about the filters you have set (if any)